# Java DOM XML Parser with chaning namespaces

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-namespaces

I do REST calls to a WebService and receive always XML as response. Then i'm parsing that XML und filling Java objects with those informations. 
The Problem is that the element-tags could have different namespaces, like this:

```
  <ns:title>....</ns:title>
```

or

```
  <ns2:title>....<ns2:title>
```

or

```
  <title>...<title>
```

EDIT:
And the namespace URIs look like this:

```
 <ns2:feed xmlns="http://www.example.com/routing1/routing2" 
 xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/../Atom" 
 xmlns:ns3="http://www.example.com/routing1/routing2"
 xmlns:ns4="http://purl.org/routing1/routing2/1.0">
```

So therefore i changed the method `element.getElementsByTagNameNS("specifiedNamespace", "title")` to `element.getElementsByTagNameNS("*", "title")`.
Is that okay to match all namespace, because i have also the case that the element-tag doesn't have a namespace like the third example `<title>..</title>`..

Is there a better procedure, to solve that problem? Or is it okay to solve it like, how i do it?

Thanks.

EDIT: 2 response examples

1.

```
<ns2:feed xmlns="http://www.example.com/routing1/routing2" xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/../Atom" xmlns:ns3="http://www.example.com/routing1/routing2" xmlns:ns4="http://purl.org/routing1/routing2/1.0">
  ...
  <ns2:someTag1>..</ns2:someTag1>
  <ns2:title>title</ns2:title>
  <entry>...</entry>
  ....
</ns2:feed>
```

2

```
<ns2:feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/../Atom" xmlns:ns2="http://www.example.com/routing1/routing2" xmlns:ns3="http://www.example.com/routing1/routing2" xmlns:ns4="http://purl.org/routing1/routing2/1.0">
  ...
  <someTag1>..<someTag1>
  <title>title<title>
  <ns2:entry>...</ns2:entry>
  ....
</ns2:feed>
```

Comment: Those aren't different namespaces. Those are different prefixes. Are the namespace URIs actually different?

Comment: Yes, the URIs are different..

Comment: Could you show us the parts with the `xmlns:ns` and `xmlns:ns2`?

Comment: I do a edit with the ns uris

Comment: So it looks like you're consuming an RSS feed. When the prefix is `ns`, does your XML have `xmlns:ns="http://www.w3.org/../Atom"` or is it some completely different URL?

Comment: Thats not fix, the uri of xmlns:ns and xmlns:ns2 interchange always..

Comment: I didn't say anything was a fix. I was asking you a question. Could you show us two full examples of actual XML responses with one that uses `<ns:title>` and another that uses `<ns2:title>` (or something else)?

Comment: I included two response examples..

Answer (score 0):

Your `title` elements have the same namespace in both of your examples.

In the first example, you have:

```
 xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/../Atom"
```

and

```
 <ns2:title>title</ns2:title>
```

so this means that `title` is in the `http://www.w3.org/../Atom` namespace.

In the second example, you have:

```
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/../Atom"
```

and

```
 <title>title<title>
```

so here again `title` is in the `http://www.w3.org/../Atom` namespace.

The prefixes are different (the second example isn't using a prefix for `title`), but the namespace is the same.

This means that you should be able to use:

```
element.getElementsByTagNameNS("http://www.w3.org/../Atom", "title")
```

and it should successfully select the `title` element, even if the prefixes change.

Comment: I tried it, but i get always null returned.. and if i put "*" as first parameter it works...

Comment: I'm curious why you have those two dots in the Atom namespace. The standard namespace for the Atom format is `http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom`. Does your XML really have those two dots, or does it have `2005`?

Comment: That was my intent, i just changed uri, but it's the same you said: `http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom`